# Defining the cycle functor $Z_* : \mathbf{Ch_R} → \mathbf{GrMod_R}$

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

In example (viii) of section 1.3.2 of [Category Theory in Context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf), the *$n$-cycle functor* is defined on objects as

\begin{align}
Z_n: \mathbf{Ch_R}&\to\mathbf{Mod_R} \\
C_\bullet&\mapsto \ker(d:C_{n+1}\to C_n)
\end{align}

> Considering all degrees simultaneously, the cycle functors assemble into a functor $Z_∗ : \mathbf{Ch_R} → \mathbf{GrMod_R}$ from the category of chain complexes to the category of graded $R$-modules.

It was easy to understand how $Z_n$ behaves, but I failed to define $Z_∗$. Even though $R$-modules $Z_nC_\bullet$ can be selected out of $C_\bullet$, they have to be assembled in a single graded $R$-module. How is this done?

Comment: Why should there be a multiplication?

Comment: A family of $R$-bilinear maps $Z_nC_\bullet \times Z_mC_\bullet\to Z_{n+m}C_\bullet$ defines a $R$-module structure on $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} Z_nC_\bullet \in \mathbf{GrMod_R}$. This is what happens in de Rham cohomology, so I expect something similar to take place here.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that this is my guess.

Comment: Modules don't necessarily have an "internal" multiplication like the de Rham algebra does (what you're describing is an R-algebra). I think you are infusing context into the example that is not there.

Comment: If you are taking the cycles on a chain complex with a compatible multiplication (i.e. a differential graded algebra; compatible in the sense that the Leibniz rule holds), then indeed the multiplication restricts to a multiplication on cycles (since for cycles $a$ and $b$, we have $d(ab) = (da)b \pm a(db) = 0$ since $da = db = 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a graded $R$-module? It's an $R$-module $X$ equipped with a splitting $X \cong \bigoplus_n X_n$. Here you can just define $Z_*C = \bigoplus Z_nC$, and then it is an $R$-module equipped with an obvious splitting. (As others have said, there is no multiplication here, unless there was one on $C$ compatible with the differential.)